# SQL Server (T-SQL) datetime conversion

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

A silly question maybe but I wanted clarification. I've created a script that has a date parameter like so:

```
DECLARE @dateparam as datetime
SET @dateparam = '01-01-2013 00:00:00'
```

This looks like it is working when I test it even if the date string is not in "correct" format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`. I changed my computer regional settings to English and the script still did what it was supposed to do.

Is this because of SQL Server 2008 R2 that I have in my computer that it knows how to convert the date or can I ran into trouble with using a dateformat like I have used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting `01-01-2013` won't expose issues such as which `01` is the month, and which is the day.

It's not a safe format.

The safe formats (for converting to `datetime`, rather than to `datetime2`) are:

```
YYYYMMDD                               20121201
YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss                  2012-12-01T10:43:29
YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss.mil              2012-12-01T10:43:29.337
```

Stick to those and only those. (The examples all represent the 1st December 2012)

Or, better yet, don't treat dates as strings at all, if you can avoid it. If you're, for example, calling SQL Server from .NET code, keep that dates as `DateTime`s in your code, and let ADO.NET and SQL Server deal with any required translations to make them become `datetime`s - without translating them to and from strings.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I expected but wanted a confirmation :)

Comment: @Damien What about `YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss`?

Comment: @Erike - not (proven) safe in my experience. I don't have a server to hand at present, but I'd suggest trying that format having set the system to British and converting to `datetime` and seeing whether the results match your expectations. The 3 formats I've given have been validated over many years.

Answer (score 1):

You're making an implicit conversion from something that looks like a date, but inf fact is a string ( '01-01-2013 00:00:00'). Rather than trusting on SQL Server to make the correct guess in what format the string is in, you should make the conversion explicit by specifying the format.

This can be done by using CONVERT (not CAST) and specify a 'style'. The different styles are listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx.

Comment: Hey, thank you. Using CONVERT is something I'll need to do in the future.